# How to block replies on sms sent with a short code ? Marketing Cloud mobile connect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobile, mobileconnect, sms

We're using Mobile connect with a short code to send sms to our employees and would like to prevent from receiving replies on the short code send (make it a one way send).
Is it possible to configure this in Mobile connect?
Thank you

Comment: Thank you Rafal.

Comment: Thank you Rafal. I'll try it and will keep you informed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a "From Name" in your mobile message to prevent the recipient replies the SMS.

> Only use From Names for one-way outbound communication, such as alerts, updates, and notifications. Because there’s no long code, recipients can’t respond to messages sent via From Name. To receive a response, set up a separate short code and include that number in the message. To respond, the recipient manually sends a response to the short code that was included in the message.

Reference: [From Names](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_setting_the_from_name_for_your_mobileconnect_account.htm&type=5)